# Cocoapods returning error after Xcode update

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Cocoapods was running just fine and appears that with the latest Xcode 11.2.1 version, it has caused some issues. If I open a new terminal and run `pod env` I get the error below. I have tried reinstalling cocoapods, reinstalling Xcode, cleaning the Ruby gems, nothing seems to get it to work. I am running Catalina 10.15.1. Any ideas on what to do here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Terminal app and run `sudo gem update cocoapods`

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work before. This time I deleted the ~/.cocoapods/repos folder and then ran that and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- Update Xcode 12.2 to 12.4
- In Xcode, go to: Xcode>Preferences.
- In tab "Locations" set the "Command Line Tools" to your current Xcode version.
- Then, pod install OR  pod install --no-repo-update

Works.